# Java / Scala - Get emojis from Hexacode

Tags: java, scala, unicode, emoji

Suppose I have a hexa code for an emoji, how can I generate the full emoji from the same. If its a single hexacode I am able to generate is as follows:

```
val str1 = "1F471"
val hex = Integer.parseInt(str1, 16)
println(new String(Character.toChars(hex)))
```

his prints . However, if I want to print the full emoji with skin tone given by the second component i.e 1F3FF, what needs to be done?

```
val str = "1F471 1F3FF"
val parts = str.split(" ").map(x => Integer.parseInt(x, 16))
println(mergeEmojis(new String(Character.toChars(parts(0))), new String(Character.toChars(parts(1))))) 
// how can mergeEmojis() be implemented?
```

Comment: you need a font that allow that. I doubt there is one for the console ouput

Comment: Just concatenating the two string works for [tio.run](https://tio.run/##jcxBCsIwEAXQdXOKIasMSjEouqogQsCFK08w1lArMQ3JoAXx7DHVC7j7n//4qSVHOQ/nm20ZjtR7sCNbf0mwC0G8RPUgB4kjNCC1WW00aLM0Rv6GQJFTmQqoU3A9KwkS6zsFNUKzhYNn29lYF5dsKWqcg14jiirE3rPzCrx9wolL69T@SpFaLp6HKSf1/VcLRITZP1JPEkG8c/4A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Ackdari, concatenating the characters works

```
  // method to convert array of emoji codes to emoji string
  private def toEmoji(hexCodes: Array[Int]): String = {
    var emojiCharsCombined: Array[Char] = Array.emptyCharArray
    hexCodes.foreach(emojiComponent => {
      val emojiChars: Array[Char] = Character.toChars(emojiComponent)
      emojiCharsCombined = concat(emojiCharsCombined, emojiChars)
    })
    new String(emojiCharsCombined)
  }
```